# python iterator over multiple lists

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have a list of lists and want to get an iterator over every element in every list.

My idea is to write a class with two variables: The iterator over the lists and the iterate over the current inner list. Whenever the inner list iterator raises StopIteration I call next on the outer list iterator. My way of doing this contains a lot of nested ifs in the next function so I'm asking you what the pythonic way of doing this is.

Example:

```
lists = [[1, 2].__iter__(), [3, 4].__iter__()]
```

Now I need an iterator object that iterates over 1, 2, 3 and 4. Because the list's I'm working with are very big I can only use iterators.

Comment: Are you asking for [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)?

Comment: I don't quite follow. Please post the code you have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

for elem in chain.from_iterable(nested_list):
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> nested_list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> for elem in chain.from_iterable(nested_list):
...     print elem,
... 
a b c d
```

Answer (score 1):

Use izip: `izip(*nested)` or  just 'zip' if your on Python 3.x

The `*` operator is the argument unpacking operator and it allows a tuple or a list to be 'spread out' through statements. Another example of this is:

```
list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

a, *bcd, e = list # a=1, bcd=[2,3,4] and e=5
```